# Disabled Products Appear Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product

In the current store Magento 1.9.2.1 I'm working I can't figure it out yet why disabled products appear in the frontend, for example in product view and search results.

Already reindexed, no flat catalog, no cache.

Comment: is it in Listing page or even individually?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri both, list and individual. Very strange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed setting the attribute scope of the 'status' to global.
The reason of the issue was that in some of the store views the value was not set to default.
Having the attribute on global scope prevents to have this confusion and all the statuses of the products only refer to the default setting.