# Magento 1.9 Disabled products displayed in Search

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I am working on Magento 1.9 and facing a issue where the disabled products are showing up in search suggestion as well as in search results.

What i have tried

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79888/62788
2. set it's visibility to Not visible individually

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Did you customize the search or using any extension?

Comment: Neither i have customized the search nor used any extension.

Comment: Then you are missing something. Try to reindex the search and also product attributes and flush the cache and try again.

Comment: Tried , Still not working for me.

Comment: check the productCollection in which its filtered

Comment: are you using any custom extension for auto search sug?

Comment: do you have multiple store views? Is the visibility and status set on the wrong store view perhaps?

Comment: This is now fixed. In my case this was due to the Radis cache. I have removed the entries of disabled products from the Radis Cache and it seems working fine.